# Is there some kind of IDE for bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I really don't like writing all of my queries within a browser, and would like to integrate VC into our team's process.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [superQuery](https://www.superquery.io). It's a full-fledged IDE for Google BigQuery with all the features you would like to find in modern IDE, web-based, including multi-tab, collaboration, git integration, cost controls, result visualizations, shareable boards, auto-complete and more!

P.S. Full disclosure, I work for [DoiT International](http://www.doit-intl.com) who has recently acquired superQuery.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does have [ODBC and JDBC drivers](http://www.simba.com/drivers/bigquery-odbc-jdbc/) which should allow you to connect to it via most SQL tools, although performance will not be equivalent to native BigQuery operations/query. If what you want is better visualization and navigation support, [Google DataStudio using BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio) may be useful. Aqua Data Studio has also recently [built support for BigQuery](https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/New-Features-17.0/page/0/What-s-New-in-Version-17-0).

Comment: We currently use DataStudio...I was meaning more of a development tool. I'll look into setting ODBC up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [SQLTools VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools) helpful - it has a [BigQuery Driver](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Evidence.sqltools-bigquery-driver)

It’s an open source project.

Disclaimer: I have contributed to this project